# Combination and permutation probability

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find a formula to solve this question:

A frog only moves forward, but it can move in steps 1 inch long or in jumps 2 inches long. A frog can cover the same distance using different combinations of steps and jumps.

Write a function that calculates the number of different combinations a frog can use to cover a given distance.

For example, a distance of 3 inches can be covered in three ways: step-step-step, step-jump, and jump-step.

Comment: Let $f_n$ be the number of ways the frog can cover a distance $n$. Show that $f$ satisfies the recurrence $f_{n+1}=f_n+f_{n-1}$. We get the Frogonacci sequemce.

Answer (score 0):

another way?

$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor{n\over 2}\rfloor}{{n-i}\choose i}$  for $0$ through $\lfloor{n\over 2}\rfloor$ $2$ inch jumps into $n$ minus that number as each $2$ inch jump added subtracts one $1$ inch jump.